# Copying a search button from one site to another: How does this search button work, and how can I reproduce its action?

Tags: javascript, forms, search, webforms, default

I have a main site, mainwebsite.org, and a sub-site that uses a different domain, mainwebsite.giftgiving.org that is styled to look the same as the main site so that users do not feel as though they've left the original site.

The main site has a search button, and I need that search button to work on the secondary site. However, I don't entirely understand how the submit function of the search button works, so I'm not sure how to get it working right on the secondary site. Simply copying the html didn't work, which I assume is because I'm either missing some javascript function or because the submit button is trying to post to a page that doesn't actually exist on the secondary site (I had a similar issue with a different website, where a submit button submitted to "../searchpage.aspx" but that page only existed on www.mainsite.org, so secondarysite.org/searchpage.aspx resulted in 'page not found'). As it is now though, I'm not getting any error, the search button simply doesn't do anything.

Here's the HTML from the main site:

```
<div id="ctl00_pnlSearch002" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_btnSearch002')">
    <div class="utilities floatRight">
        <ul>
            <li class="searchButton"><input type="image" name="ctl00$btnSearch002" id="ctl00_btnSearch002" src="/images/design002/btn_search.jpg" style="width: 30px; height: 22px; border: none;"></li>
            <li class="search"><input name="ctl00$txtSearch" type="text" id="ctl00_txtSearch" value="Search" onblur="if (value == '') {value = 'Search'}" onfocus="if (value == 'Search') {value =''}"></li>
            <li class="paddingL"><a href="javascript:textResizer.doResize(1)" class="aPlus">A+</a><a href="javascript:textResizer.doResize(-1)" class="aMinus">A-</a></li>
            <li class="textsize paddingL">Text Size</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand how this line works:

```
onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ct100_btnSearch002')
```

If I could figure out where the search button is making a call to, I could modify the secondary site by putting the search button inside a form with action="http://mainwebsite.org/?????"

Answer (score 0):

That one line that you don't understand triggers a JavaScript function that in this case likely ends up performing a postback:  WebForm_FireDefaultButton() performs a virtual "click" on the named element, in this case, "ct100_btnSearch002".

(There's a copy of the source code to that JS function here, although you can easily disassemble MS's helper JS yourself to see it:  http://www.sentia.com.au/blog/fixing-the-enter-key-in-aspnet-with-jquery)

That button very likely performs a postback on the original page, triggering some "OnClick" event of the "btnSearch002" control.  Since you've only shown the resulting HTML and not the original .aspx file it came from, or the .aspx.cs file that contains the server-side code that responds to that postback, it's going to be very hard to tell you much more.

But odds are pretty good that you can't simply copy that "search" button from site to site:  Copying that markup is copying just the tip of the iceberg, and leaves out the rest of the berg that's holding up that tip.